# If I get a complete and valid HttpWebResponse but the contents are invalid, what type of exception should be thrown?

Tags: c#, json, exception

What I'm doing is grabbing JSON off a website to deserialise it with a `DataContract` class. So what if the response I get doesn't match the class? I would be getting a `SerializationException`, but I'm thinking it would be better as an InnerException to a different exception, as the response is therefore incomplete or not JSON at all.

Right now I'm thinking WebException, but I have no ideas for a WebExceptionStatus that would be correct. Or perhaps it would be better to just create a completely new exception type?

Comment: Is there a specific reason other than the one you described why you want to transform this exception? Are you going to use it in a specific way for which you need to wrap it?

Comment: I'm not really sure on what you're asking, but this exception is occurring in a library and I'm thinking about some way that would make it easier to handle such exceptions and know its definite reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create something inheriting off Exception and setting the InnerException to the SerializationException, since I can catch the specific class.